# Making some primitive cardboard waves move with canvas

Tags: jquery, css, canvas, html5-canvas, alpha

I've written a script that draws a very cartoony, primitive wave;

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, 12);
var waux=120;
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    context.quadraticCurveTo(5+(waux*i), 0, (10+(waux*i)), 6);
    context.quadraticCurveTo((60+(waux*i)), 56, (120+(waux*i)), 6);
}
context.lineWidth = 1;
context.strokeStyle = 'black';
context.stroke();
```

..Now I'm wondering if you guys could help me make the line move (without moving the div) and have everything above the line be transparent. Like a cardboard cut-out of a wave eternally moving sideways!

Thanks in advanced!! I put the code up over at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PDAXG/2/) for you guys to look at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your code slightly so you draw a complete path around the bottom screen in order to be able to fill it and keep top transparent:

```
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(0, canvas.height);
context.lineTo(0, 12);

var waux=120;
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
    context.quadraticCurveTo(5+(waux*i), 0, (10+(waux*i)), 6);
    context.quadraticCurveTo((60+(waux*i)), 56, (120+(waux*i)), 6);
}
context.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height);
context.closePath();

context.fillStyle = 'blue';
context.fill();
```

Then add an animation function which translate the canvas with `delta` and an offset used as counter for repeating the animation over and over:

```
var offset = 0;
var delta = 2;
// ...

function animate() {
    context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,30);

    context.save();
    context.translate(-offset, 0);
    drawWave();
    context.restore();

    offset += delta;
    if (offset > 120) offset=0;
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

The value of `delta` determines the speed.

<kbd>**[UPDATED DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/PDAXG/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Is there a way I can reuse the animate and drawWave classes? I need various waves moving at different speeds! I tried sending canvas and context as parameters, but that didn't work.

Comment: @serv-bot22 use different layers of canvases (just put them on top of each other). Then you can draw the wave at different positions at various speeds, with less fuzz.

Comment: What do you mean by less fuzz? I ended up doing that. Thanks! I also applied a pattern fill on the waves and added some 'shadow' waves behind the pattern ones.

Comment: @serv-bot22 by less fuzz I mean less complicated. Layers are good in situation like this (as you do now) - you can always optimize the draw code and do all in one, but here is where the "fuzz" comes in. :-)

Comment: BTW; I'm having trouble filling the wave with a pattern. It loads sometimes on chrome and firefox straight-up gives me an null object on this line--> var fillColor = Ccontext.createPattern(pattern,'repeat');


I'll make a new post with the issue.